# problems POSTing data to my WCF service

Tags: wcf, http, post

I am trying to set up a simple service that will allow the user to pass in a Pickup object as XML in the body of a POST.  If i set the service to receive a Stream type, i can get it to work fine, but I'm not sure what i need to change in order for it to instead of a custom type is works fine.  When I tell the server to expect a Pickup type i get "Request Error.  The server has encountered..."

I someone could tell me what i need to change in the server/client to get this to work i would appreciate it very much.

My data Contract

```
[DataContract]
public class Pickup
{        
    [DataMember]
    public string DelZip
    { get; set; }

}
```

Operation Contract

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "/pickups",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string RequestPickup(Pickup pickup);


    public string RequestPickup(Pickup pu)
    {
        return pu.DelZip;
    }
```

config

```
      <services>
  <service name="TestAPI.Services.TestServices" >
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"
              contract="TestAPI.Services.ITestServices" />
  </service>
</services>    
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>      
</behaviors>
```

my client code

```
 const string url = "http://localhost:18463/TestServices.svc/pickups";
                req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.ContentType = "application/xml";                

                var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument { XmlResolver = null };
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(@"<Pickup><DelZip>55555</DelZip></Pickup>");
                string sXml = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
                req.ContentLength = sXml.Length;
                var sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
                sw.Write(sXml);
                sw.Close();

                res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = res.GetResponseStream();
                var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
```

Comment: Rather than building the xml yourself its better to use a DataContractSerializer class that would serialize and deserialize the object. Since the WCF framework by default uses the above class it would be able to deserialize the xml string back to object on the server

Comment: The problem with that is that clients consuming the service will be written on any and all platforms so I need to be able to be able to get it to function correctly without relying specifically on any .net classes.

Comment: Then it would be easy to have an xmlString as a param rather than a POCO object. If you still want to use the POCO object i guess the xml you build must be missing the namespace attribute.